# How many balloons are possible to be bloated up?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, ideal-gas

> A cylinder of volume $12 L$ is filled up with helium gas. Temperature and pressure of that cylinder are $281 K$ and $13 \ atm$ respectively. If one balloon can consume $1.4 L$ gas and pressure and temperature become $1.5 atm$ and $298 K$ respectively, then how many balloons are possible to be bloated up?

**Given Solution**

\begin{align} \frac {{P_0}{V_0}}{T_0}=\frac {{P_1}{V_1}}{T_1}
\end{align}
\begin{align} => \frac {13×12}{281}=\frac {{1.5}{V_1}}{298}
\end{align}
\begin{align} =>{V_1}=110.2918
\end{align}
Now,
\begin{align} {V_1}-12=1.4n
\end{align}
\begin{align} 110.2918-12=1.4n
\end{align}
\begin{align} n≈70
\end{align}

But my question is why did they take ${V_0}=12L$ ? ${V_0}$ indicates the volume of gas which leaves the cylinder during the time of filling all balloons and ${V_0}$ is the volume of the amount of gas when it remains in the cylinder. Not all gases are sucked out from the cylinder and also the amount of gas which goes into the balloon makes up a part of the cylinder but not the entire cylinder. Right?

Comment: The gas remaining in the cylinder ist deducted in the line before the end..